# Define getter Mongo_dart Flutter

Tags: mongodb, flutter, dart, mongo-dart

why does it say "The getter 'fieldName' isn't defined for the type 'Map<String, dynamic>'" when I would have to return a fieldname.

```
import 'package:mongo_dart/mongo_dart.dart';

 var db = Db("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test"); 
 await db.open();
 var collection = db.collection('Users');     
 await collection.find().forEach(
             (users) {
               dbfieldName = users.fieldName; // This is where the problem occurs.
             },
           );
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The method `find` retrieves many documents, so any `users` that you get is a document (in Map format). Now I have not clear what you want to do with `fieldName`.
If you want all field names for the document `users` you can do:

```dart
print(users.keys);
```

if you want the value of the field 'foo' you have to fetch it from the map:

```dart
var fieldValue = users['foo'];
```